# Rgdal package installation on Amazon Linux AMI

Tags: r, gis, gdal, rgdal

I've installed geos, proj-4.8.0 and gdal-1.9.2, yet, after installing the R package rgeos, rgdal fails to install.

Here is a look at my home directory:
[image]

. . . and the error I get running `install.packages("rgdal", type="source")`:

> ** building package indices
>   ** installing vignettes
>   ** testing if installed package can be loaded
>   Error in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...) : 
>     unable to load shared object '/mainstorage/michaeld/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.1/rgdal/libs/rgdal.so':
>     libgdal.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
>   Error: loading failed
>   Execution halted
>   ERROR: loading failed
>   * removing ‘/mainstorage/michaeld/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.1/rgdal’
>
> The downloaded source packages are in
>       ‘/tmp/Rtmpt51iFG/downloaded_packages’
>   Warning message:
>   In install.packages("rgdal", type = "source") :
>     installation of package ‘rgdal’ had non-zero exit status

I infer that this error has something to do with a dependent library. . . but that is all I gather.

I should mention that running `sudo yum install libgdal1 libgdal1-dev libgeos libgeos-dev` as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21683138/unable-to-install-rgdal-and-rgeos-r-libraries-on-red-hat-linux) yields the following:

> No package libgdal1 available.
>   No package libgdal1-dev available.
>   Package geos-3.4.2-1.3.amzn1.x86_64 already installed and latest version
>   No package libgeos-dev available.

So, perhaps the better question is how do I install these `dev` packages?

Thanks for any direction.

Comment: Maybe... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15248815/rgdal-package-installation

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to update the dynamic library cache, using `ldconfig` as superuser.

Alternatively, rather than building the packages from source, you can [enable the Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux (EPEL) repository](http://aws.amazon.com/amazon-linux-ami/faqs/#epel).